# How to access ms word text and its styles using MSAA api in python

Tags: python, msaa

From past 1 week i am searching for accessing ms word using msaa api in python, but i didn't get any info in python. So please help me on this.

I want headlines in ms word doc using msaa api in python

How to do this?

I am getting headlines in normal ms word doc form python, but i don't know how to get form msaa api.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MSAA is the most easy or appropriate way to access document text... maybe Office has a different API from Microsoft to extract data...

I recommend you check out if MSAA is supported by the object you want in ms-word using tools like Inspect32 or AccExplorer.

after that in msaa usually you do the following (in any language)
Search for the window or take the foreground window, get accessible object from handle to window and for that object get class, name, value... (accValue, accName)

You could use a library like: https://github.com/phuslu/pyMSAA
or use COM calls.